# form goes blank on use of TbExtendedGridView

Tags: yii

I am new to yii1. In my project ,I have used TblExtendedGridView to display data in the table .The form shows the data in my local computer.But when the project is uloaded in server,the file is blank and doesnot show any error.
What is the problem?

```
'<?php
$uniqid=md5(uniqid());
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'marketing-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'type' => 'striped bordered',
    'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
        'columns'=>array(
        array(
        'header'=>'#',
            'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
         ),
        array(
        'name'=>'client_id',
        'header'=>'Company',
        'value'=>'$data->clientName->client_name',
        'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:200px'),
        ),
        array(
        'name'=>'client_contact_id',
        'header'=>'Contacted',
        'value'=>'$data->contactPerson->contact_name',
        'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:180px'),
        ),
        array(
        'name'=>'visited_date',
        'header'=>'Visit Date',
        'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:100px'),
        ),
        array(
        'name'=>'possibility',
        'header'=>'Probability',
        'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:100px'),
        ),
        'remarks',
        array(
        'name'=>'next_visited_date',
        'header'=>'Next Contact Date',
        'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:100px'),
        ),
        array(
        'name'=>'follow_up_by',
        'header'=>'Follow Up By',
        'value'=>'$data->followPerson->user_name',
        'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:180px'),
        ),
         ),


        ),
    ),
)); ?>'


'My controller is:

       <?php

    class MarketingController extends Controller
    {
        public $layout='//layouts/column1';
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $this->actionAdmin();
        }

        // Uncomment the following methods and override them if needed

        public function filters()
        {
            return array(
                'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
                'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
            );
        }
        public function accessRules()
        {
            return array(
                array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                    'actions'=>array('index','view','DynamicContact'),
                    'users'=>array('*'),
                ),
                array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                    'actions'=>array('admin','delete','create','update','DynamicContact'),
                    'users'=>array('@'),
                ),
                array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                    'actions'=>array('admin','delete','DynamicContact'),
                    'users'=>array('admin','@'),
                ),
                array('deny',  // deny all users
                    'users'=>array('*'),
                ),
            );
        }

        protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='marketing-form')
            {
                echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
        }
        public function actionView($id)
        {

             EQuickDlgs::render('view',array('model'=>$this->loadModel($id)));
        }
        public function actionAdmin()
        {
            $model=new Marketing('search');
            $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
            if(isset($_GET['Marketing']))
                $model->attributes=$_GET['Marketing'];

            $this->render('admin',array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));
        }


        public function actionCreate()
        {

            $model=new Marketing;

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if(isset($_POST['Marketing']))
            {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Marketing'];
                //print_r($_POST['User']);
                //die;

                if($model->save())
                {
                    EQuickDlgs::checkDialogJsScript();
                    $this->redirect(array('marketing/admin','id'=>$model->marketing_id));


                }
            }

            EQuickDlgs::render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));

        }
        public function loadModel($id)
        {
            $model=Marketing::model()->findByPk($id);
            if($model===null)
                throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
            return $model;
        }

        public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
            if(isset($_POST['Marketing']))
            {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Marketing'];
                if($model->save())
                {
                    //$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->user_id));
                    EQuickDlgs::checkDialogJsScript();
                    $this->redirect(array('marketing/admin','id'=>$model->marketing_id));
                }

            }

            EQuickDlgs::render('update',array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));
        }

        public function actionDelete($id)
        {
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }

    }'

    'And Model is :
<?php
class Marketing extends PMActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'pm_mar_marketing';
    }


    public function rules()
    {

        return array(
            array('client_id, client_contact_id, follow_up_by, visited_date, visit_type, next_visited_date, possibility, remarks', 'required'),
            array('client_id, client_contact_id, follow_up_by, visit_type, crtd_by, updt_by, updt_cnt', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('possibility', 'length', 'max'=>20),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('marketing_id, client_id, client_contact_id, follow_up_by, visited_date, visit_type, next_visited_date, possibility, remarks', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }


    public function relations()
    {

        return array(
        'clientName' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'client_id'),
        'contactPerson' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ClientContact', 'client_contact_id'),
        'followPerson' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'follow_up_by'),
                'visitType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'CodeValue', 'visit_type')
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'marketing_id' => 'Marketing',
            'client_id' => 'Client',
                    //    'client_id'=> 'Client',
            'client_contact_id' => 'Contact Person',
            //'client_contact_id' => 'Contact Person',
            'follow_up_by' => 'Follow Up By',
            'visited_date' => 'Visited Date',
            'visitType.code_lbl' => 'Visit Type',
            'next_visited_date' => 'Next Contact Date',
            'possibility' => 'Probability',
            'remarks' => 'Remarks',
            'crtd_by' => 'Crtd By',
            'crtd_dt' => 'Crtd Dt',
            'updt_by' => 'Updt By',
            'updt_dt' => 'Updt Dt',
            'updt_cnt' => 'Updt Cnt',
        );
    }


    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array('clientName','contactPerson','followPerson');

        $criteria->compare('marketing_id',$this->marketing_id);
        $criteria->compare('clientName.client_name',$this->client_id,true);
        $criteria->compare('contactPerson.contact_name',$this->client_contact_id,true);
        $criteria->compare('followPerson.user_name',$this->follow_up_by,true);
        $criteria->compare('visited_date',$this->visited_date,true);
        //$criteria->compare('visit_type',$this->visit_type);
        $criteria->compare('next_visited_date',$this->next_visited_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('possibility',$this->possibility,true);
        $criteria->compare('remarks',$this->remarks,true);
        $criteria->compare('crtd_by',$this->crtd_by);
        $criteria->compare('crtd_dt',$this->crtd_dt,true);
        $criteria->compare('updt_by',$this->updt_by);
        $criteria->compare('updt_dt',$this->updt_dt,true);
        $criteria->compare('updt_cnt',$this->updt_cnt);
        //$criteria -> join = 'INNER JOIN pm_marketing_user followPerson on t.follow_up_by= followPerson.user_id';

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }


    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
'
```

Comment: In localhost you are using windows?

Comment: yes i am using windows.

Comment: please show your controller and your model

Comment: I am using PHP  of version 5.3.1 where as in server PHP version is 5.3.29. Does PHP version plays any role in this?

Comment: I think No.  I think is somethings related to Upper/Lower Case. But  which action doese'nt work?

Comment: This happend only with this view? - And please tell me  which action in your controller don't show the result?

Comment: yes i have got problem only with this view. i have used TbExtendedGridView in other forms too.Other form have got no problem.the method is actionAdmin().

Comment: Check for the lowercase uppercase of the class code file (Marketing.php i guess)

Comment: i didn't get that? can you explain more?

Comment: If your dev env is windows and your prod env is Unxi like can happen yuo have marketing.php in your model and you referer to Marketing.php this work in windows/dos but not in Unix like O.S.

Comment: ok i found out solution to my problem .It was uppercase/lowercase issue.Thank you for helping!!!!

Comment: Ok write the solution in the form of answer so that it can also be useful for others. if the answers they have been useful for you please mark the answer as accepted and/or as useful,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If This happend only whit this view check for the lowercase/uppercase of the class code file (Marketing.php i guess)

If your development enviroment  is windows and your produdction enviroment is Unix like,  can happen yuo have marketing.php in your model and you referer to Marketing.php or to the contrary this work in windows/dos because in case insentisitve  but not in Unix like O.S.

Comment: While defining relation the class name i mentioned was in uppercase i.e 'Client' but the class name was in lowercase i.e 'client'